# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification 28.0.0 vs 26.1.0

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I know this was asked here like 100 times before, and I have checked similar questions, but still can't solve it.

In my case, Android Studio says:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0

So I have checked Gradle dependency tree:

```
+--- com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1 -> 28.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support.test:monitor:1.0.2
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1 -> 28.0.0
|    +--- junit:junit:4.12
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    \--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.0.2
|    +--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
|    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3 (*)
|    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
+--- com.android.support.test:runner:{strictly 1.0.2} -> 1.0.2 (c)
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support.test:monitor:{strictly 1.0.2} -> 1.0.2 (c)
+--- junit:junit:{strictly 4.12} -> 4.12 (c)
+--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:{strictly 1.3} -> 1.3 (c)
+--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:{strictly 2.3.0} -> 2.3.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:{strictly 3.0.2} -> 3.0.2 (c)
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:{strictly 3.0.2} -> 3.0.2 (c)
+--- com.squareup:javawriter:{strictly 2.1.1} -> 2.1.1 (c)
+--- javax.inject:javax.inject:{strictly 1} -> 1 (c)
+--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:{strictly 1.3} -> 1.3 (c)
+--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:{strictly 1.3} -> 1.3 (c)
+--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 2.0.1} -> 2.0.1 (c)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:support-compat:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:collections:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:{strictly 1.1.1} -> 1.1.1 (c)
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:{strictly 1.1.1} -> 1.1.1 (c)
+--- android.arch.core:common:{strictly 1.1.1} -> 1.1.1 (c)
+--- com.android.support:versionedparcelable:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:cursoradapter:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:documentfile:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:loader:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:{strictly 1.1.1} -> 1.1.1 (c)
+--- android.arch.core:runtime:{strictly 1.1.1} -> 1.1.1 (c)
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:{strictly 1.1.1} -> 1.1.1 (c)
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:{strictly 1.1.1} -> 1.1.1 (c)
+--- com.android.support:localbroadcastmanager:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:print:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:support-fragment:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:customview:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:viewpager:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:drawerlayout:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:interpolator:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:asynclayoutinflater:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:{strictly 28.0.0} -> 28.0.0 (c)
+--- android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:{strictly 1.1.1} -> 1.1.1 (c)
+--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:{strictly 1.1.1} -> 1.1.1 (c)
+--- android.arch.persistence:db-framework:{strictly 1.1.1} -> 1.1.1 (c)
+--- android.arch.persistence:db:{strictly 1.1.1} -> 1.1.1 (c)
+--- com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:{strictly 1.9.5} -> 1.9.5 (c)
+--- org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:{strictly 15.0} -> 15.0 (c)
+--- pub.devrel:easypermissions:{strictly 2.0.1} -> 2.0.1 (c)
+--- org.locationtech.jts:jts:{strictly 1.16.1} -> 1.16.1 (c)
+--- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:{strictly 0.34.0} -> 0.34.0 (c)
+--- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:{strictly 4.5.0} -> 4.5.0 (c)
+--- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-core:{strictly 4.5.0} -> 4.5.0 (c)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:{strictly 2.8.5} -> 2.8.5 (c)
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:{strictly 2.4.0} -> 2.4.0 (c)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.14.1} -> 3.14.1 (c)
+--- com.squareup.okio:okio:{strictly 1.17.2} -> 1.17.2 (c)
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:{strictly 2.4.0} -> 2.4.0 (c)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:{strictly 3.11.0} -> 3.11.0 (c)
+--- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-geojson:{strictly 4.5.0} -> 4.5.0 (c)
+--- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:{strictly 4.5.0} -> 4.5.0 (c)
+--- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:{strictly 1.2.0} -> 1.2.0 (c)
+--- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:{strictly 4.2.0} -> 4.2.0 (c)
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:{strictly 1.1.0} -> 1.1.0 (c)
+--- com.mapbox.navigator:mapbox-navigation-native:{strictly 6.1.0} -> 6.1.0 (c)
+--- com.jakewharton.timber:timber:{strictly 4.7.1} -> 4.7.1 (c)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:{strictly 16.0.0} -> 16.0.0 (c)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:{strictly 16.0.1} -> 16.0.1 (c)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:{strictly 16.0.1} -> 16.0.1 (c)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:{strictly 26.1.0} -> 26.1.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:{strictly 26.1.0} -> 26.1.0 (c)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:{strictly 16.0.1} -> 16.0.1 (c)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:{strictly 16.0.0} -> 16.0.0 (c)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:collections:28.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1
|    |    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0
|    |    |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:collections:28.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:collections:28.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:cursoradapter:28.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:documentfile:28.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:loader:28.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1
|    |    |    |    +--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0
|    |    |    |    |    \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.1
|    |    |    |    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:localbroadcastmanager:28.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:print:28.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:customview:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:viewpager:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:customview:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:customview:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:drawerlayout:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:customview:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:customview:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:interpolator:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:interpolator:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:asynclayoutinflater:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:cursoradapter:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:loader:28.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0 (*)
+--- android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1
|    +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0
|    +--- android.arch.persistence:db-framework:1.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0
|    |    \--- android.arch.persistence:db:1.1.1
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0
|    +--- android.arch.persistence:db:1.1.1 (*)
|    +--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
+--- com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5
+--- org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0
+--- pub.devrel:easypermissions:2.0.1
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0 (*)
+--- org.locationtech.jts:jts:1.16.1
+--- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.34.0
|    +--- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:4.5.0
|    |    +--- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-core:4.5.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5
|    |    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0 -> 3.14.1
|    |    |    |         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2
|    |    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2 -> 2.8.5
|    |    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0
|    |    |         \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0 -> 3.14.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-geojson:4.5.0
|    |         \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5
|    +--- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:4.5.0
|    |    +--- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-core:4.5.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-geojson:4.5.0 (*)
|    +--- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:1.2.0
|    +--- com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:4.2.0
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0 -> 3.14.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2 -> 2.8.5
|    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0
|    |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0 -> 1.1.1 (*)
|    |         +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0 -> 1.1.1 (*)
|    |         +--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0 -> 1.1.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
|    |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0 -> 1.1.1 (*)
|    |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.0 -> 1.1.1 (*)
|    |         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0 -> 1.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.mapbox.navigator:mapbox-navigation-native:6.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1 (*)
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0
    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1
    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1
    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0
    |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0
    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1
    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:16.0.0
    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
```

I am quite confused from this output. It seems that for example `com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2` needs `com.android.support:support-v4:{strictly 26.1.0}`, but I couldn't find any newer version than `1.0.2` of mentioned library. Also at same time is needs `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:{strictly 28.0.0}`. So it basically needs the same library in two versions?? **I am really not sure what to think about this, let alone to fix it. Please help** :D

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sanctusmedia.android.WattsUp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.07"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'

    // Room persistence library (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html#java)
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"

    // https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader, Apache 2.0 license
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

    // Easy permissions: https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions, Apache 2.0 license
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:2.0.1'

    // JTS Topology Suite - predecessor of GEOS: https://github.com/locationtech/jts, EDL v1.0 license
    implementation group: 'org.locationtech.jts', name: 'jts', version: '1.16.1', ext: 'pom'

    // MapBox, see: https://www.mapbox.com
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.34.0'

    // OkHTTP, see: https://github.com/square/okhttp, Apache 2.0 license
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1")

    // Google Play services for faster GPS lock
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
}

configurations {
    cleanedAnnotations
    compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains' , module:'annotations'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `support-v4` is required by the play services (`play-services-location`) in version 26.1.0, but not anywhere else with a 28 version, so that it is not automatically upgraded.

What happen if you do this yourself by adding :

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of us (android developers in AS) have same problem! I searched about it and finally give up and tell myself this is another bug of android and none of my business!

finally I Add this line to my dependencies to get ride of warning!

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0"
```

Now i use **androidX** and this problem not happens anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because of

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

If you remove this line, dependencies are ok.

```
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1
     |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
     |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
     |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0
     |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0
     |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
     |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
     |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
     |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:16.0.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
     \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with these step.

1. Find out the support lib version force changed dependencies
2. `implementation` these lib with a `exclude` command, this will keep you implement the main dependency and exclude the group you set.
3. Manually `implementation` the support lib with a certain version.
4. After doing this you can print the dependency tree again and check the support lib version in the same dependency. Compare it with the not `exclude` one

For example

**eg 1**

```
+--- com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1 -> 28.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support.test:monitor:1.0.2
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1 -> 28.0.0
|    +--- junit:junit:4.12
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    \--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
```

according to the dependency tree you have post.

`com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2` dependence the `com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1` and the support lib version force change to `28.0.0`, you can do like below.

```
implementation ('com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}

implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
```

`exclude` command can exclude the `group` what you set, then manually `implementation` support lib with version `28.0.0`

**eg 2**

```
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0
    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1
    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1
    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0
    |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0
    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)
    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1
    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:16.0.0
    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 (*)
    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
```

In this case

```
implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}

implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
```

**I did not list all the case but just follow the rules i think i may help!**

Answer (score 0):

It's an alternative solution to override during dependency resolution. You can put the follow snippet in root level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "28.0.0"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```